# Pivot or Melt a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, melt

I have a DataFrame that has the following columns: 'Series Name', 'Country Name', '2000', '20001' , ..., '2018'.
In 'Series Name' I have the variables that I want to analize (for example, 'PBI', 'Surface Area', etc). So, in 'Series Name' I have repeated values (PBI for each Country, for example).

[Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol5Qx.png)

| Series Name | Country Name | 2000 [YR2000] | 2001 [YR2001] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados) | Estados Unidos | 9632030 | 9632030 |
| Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados) | Unión Europea | 4384964,995 | 4384984,995 |
| Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados) | Japón | 377800 | 377880 |

I want to reorder the DataFrame in this way:
- Columns: 'Country Name', 'Year' and all the unique values of 'Series Name'
- Year column: take the the values from 2000 to 2018 for each Country
- 'Series Name' columns : each column ('PBI', 'Surface' etc) has the value for the respective
Year and Country.

| Country Name | Year | Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Estados Unidos | 2000 | 9632030 |
| Estados Unidos | 2001 | 9632030 |
| Unión Europea | 2000 | 4384964,995 |
| Unión Europea | 2001 | 4384964,995 |
| Japón | 2000 | 377800 |
| Japón | 2001 | 377800 |

I tried with melt, but I really don´t know how to use it:

```
indicadores_clean_pv = pd.melt(indicadores_clean, id_vars=['Country Name'], var_name='Año')
```

[What I Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdNkN.png)

I´ve also tried :

```
indicadores_clean_pv.melt(id_vars='Country Name', var_name='Year').groupby(['Country Name','Year']).agg({'Series Name':'first'}).reset_index()
```

But I can't put the 'Series Name' values in the columns

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='Country Name', columns='Series Name', 
                      aggfunc='first', sort=False)
         .rename_axis(columns=['Year', None])
         .stack('Year').reset_index()
         .assign(Year=lambda x: x['Year'].str.split().str[0]))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Country Name  Year Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados)
0  Estados Unidos  2000                           9632030
1  Estados Unidos  2001                           9632030
2   Unión Europea  2000                       4384964,995
3   Unión Europea  2001                       4384984,995
4           Japón  2000                            377800
5           Japón  2001                            377880
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try simple `.stack()`/`.unstack()`:

```py
out = (
    df.set_index(["Country Name", "Series Name"])
    .stack()
    .unstack(level=1)
    .rename_axis(columns=None, index=["Country Name", "Year"])
    .reset_index()
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     Country Name  Year Superficie (kilómetros cuadrados)
0  Estados Unidos  2000                           9632030
1  Estados Unidos  2001                           9632030
2           Japón  2000                            377800
3           Japón  2001                            377880
4   Unión Europea  2000                       4384964,995
5   Unión Europea  2001                       4384984,995
```

Comment: In fact, I didn't need to `melt` at all. `set_index/stack/unstack` is like a `pivot_table`. Nice.